# Set sampling algo

Tags: imagemagick, pythonmagick

Im trying to create a thumbnail from a jpg image using PythonMagick:

```
img.quality(90)
# TODO set the sampling algo e.g. bilinear
img.sample(Geometry(scaledWid, scaledHei))
img.crop(Geometry(THUMBNAIL_WID-1, THUMBNAIL_HEI-1,cropLeft, cropTop))
img.write(destFilePath)
```

How do I set the sampling algo to be used? I believe right now it is using nearest neighbor which kinda looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resizing filter is set via a property on the image set before calling `.resize()` or, I imagine, `.sample()`.

The property is `.filterType()` and is set from one of the enumerated values on `PythonMagick.FilterTypes` - which is the same list as the [Magick++ `FilterTypes`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Enumerations.html#FilterTypes).

*(NB. There is never any documentation for PythonMagick, but as it's essentially just a wrapper for [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/), just use the [API documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick++-classes.php) for that.)*

So try (untested, I don't use Python):

```
img.quality(90)

img.filterType(PythonMagick.FilterTypes.SincFilter)
img.sample(Geometry(scaledWid, scaledHei))

img.crop(Geometry(THUMBNAIL_WID-1, THUMBNAIL_HEI-1,cropLeft, cropTop))

img.write(destFilePath)
```

Note the default filter is usually `LanczosFilter`, or at least it is supposed to be, which is pretty good.